# Understanding heisenbug example: "Debuggers cause additional source code to be executed stealthily"

Tags: terminology

I read wikipedia page about heisunbug, but don't understand this example. Can anyone explain it in detail?

> Debuggers also commonly provide watches or other user interfaces that cause additional source code (such as property accessors) to be executed stealthily, which can, in turn, change the state of the program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what it's getting at is that the debugger itself may call code (such as getters) to retrieve the value of a property you might have placed a watch on.

Consider the getter:

```
def getter fahrenheit:
    return celsius * 9 / 5 + 32;
```

and what would happen if you put a watch on the `fahrenheit` property.

That code would normally only be called if your code itself tried to access the `fahrenheit` propery but, if a debugger is calling it to maintain the watch, it may be called outside of the control of your program.

A simple example, let's say the getter has a (pretty obvious) bug which means that it returns the wrong result the first time it's called:

```
class temperature:
    variable state

    def init:
        state = 1

    def getter fahrenheit:
        if state == 1:
            state = 0
            return -42
        return celsius * 9 / 5 + 32;
```

So running your code *without* a debugger exhibits a problem in that it will return a weird value the first time your code calls it.

But, if your *debugger* is actually calling the getter to extract a value that it's watching (and it's probably doing this after *every* single-step operation you perform), that means the getter will be well and truly returning the *correct* value by the time your code calls it for what *it* thinks is the first time.

Hence the problem will disappear when you try to look closer at it, and that's the very *definition* of a Heisenbug, despite the fact that Heisenberg's *actual* uncertainty principle has little to do with the observer effect.